# configuring log4j for loggin-channel-adaptor

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration to process a message from Message queue using a `jms-message-driven-channel-adaptor` which puts the message into `processMessage` channel. I have configured a `wire-tap` to intercept the message and log the message to a log file.

I want to log only the payload to the log file but when I start my application, all the application level logs are also getting logged into the log file along with the payload.

Below is the spring configuration and log4j configuration for more details.

Spring Configuration:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    channel="processMessage" destination-name="MyTest.Queue"/>

<int:channel id="processMessage">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"></int:wire-tap>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="logger" logger-name="myLogger"
    level="INFO" log-full-message="true">
</int:logging-channel-adapter>
```

Log4j Configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, myLogger
log4j.appender.myLogger=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.myLogger.File=/app/logs/jms.log
log4j.appender.myLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLogger.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want those to go to a different file you should not configure the `rootLogger` to use your appender; rootLogger should go to another appender.

Also, you need a category for your logger

```
log4j.category.myLogger=INFO, myAppender
```

(change your appender name to myAppender).

**EDIT**

I just tested with this and it works as expected...

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" logger-name="tapInbound"
    level="INFO" />
```

.

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.category.tapInbound=INFO, myAppender

log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.File=/tmp/jms.log
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. But how to mention the `myLogger` inside the `<int:logging-channel-adapter`. I am not able to log the message to the log file under the `myLogger` category.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have Log4J config like:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, myLogger
```

therefore all the categories use the your custom appender.

Maybe `stdout` for them:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%t] [%c] - %m%n
```

?